# variable not accessible after #If directive

Tags: autohotkey

```
var1 := "this works"

#If WinActive("")
d::d
#If

var2 := "this doesn't"

x::
    MsgBox, %var1%, %var2%
return
```

When the hotkey is triggered, it only displays var1, acting like var2 doesn't exist at all.
Why does this happen and what can I do to access var2 from the hotkey?
I can't move var2 up, since my actual code is split accross two files.

Comment: d::d is the troublemaker. Replace it with say "var3=3" and rerun

Comment: d::d is a paceholder for several hotkeys, that need to only execute under a certain #if directive. I have two files with hotkeys for two different programs, and I need to use variables in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a **variable** between or after  hotkeys or hotstrings. 
Hotkeys/Hotstrings terminate the automatic execution of code lines and the line

```
var2 := "this doesn't"
```

never becomes true because is never executed.

**A variable has to be defined**

- in the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script before the first return or hotkey),
- or in a hotkey/hotstring,
- or in a label (subroutine),
- or in a function.

Comment: Thanks. What is the "correct" way to define variables in an #include'd file then?

Comment: The [#Include](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm) directive causes the script to behave as though the specified file's contents are present at the exact position where you put it in the main script. This way the included file becomes a part of the main script. You can define variables in an included file only if this file's contents are part of the auto-execute section, or of a hotkey/label/or function.